# How to get the value of quantity entered in the input field in single product page to input field in cart page in magento?

Tags: magento

I have build a ecommerce website in magento. In the website, I have a single product page for all products which has a quantity input field, When I am entering a value in the quantity input field and clicking the add to cart button, it goes to a cart which also has a quantity input field but it doesnot show the value inputted in the quantity field in the single product page. Can anyone tell how to solve this issue ?

In the database, sales_flat_item has a quantity attribute but has a default value 1 being stored.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

What name you have assigned to your Quantity box? As you described, it seems all things are working properly. You have to only assign the name attribute of quantity field as "qty" than it will automatically put the user inserted quantity to cart page.

Ex: -

```
<input name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty"
class="input-text qty" type="text">
```